# How to create S3 bucket via CloudFormation with Transfer Acceleration on by default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

My Serverless project creates an S3 bucket, I would like it to have Transfer Acceleration turned-on by default.

I have tried this:

```
"UploaderS3Bucket": {
  "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
  "Properties": {
    "BucketName": "${uploaderBucket}-${aws-environment-lower}-${stage}",
    "Accelerate": "Enabled",
    "CorsConfiguration": {
      "CorsRules": [
        {
          "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
          ],
          "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "HEAD"
          ],
          "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
          ],
          "ExposedHeaders": [
            "Etag"
          ],
          "MaxAge": "3000"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

but that isn't an accepted Property and I can't find anything appropriate in the aws docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html

Is there any way to do this during the resources deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting acceleration on an S3 bucket is not (yet) supported by CloudFormation. These things typically lag by a few weeks/months.

Updates are usually announced on the [what's new](https://aws.amazon.com/new/) page and in the docs (that you already linked).

I feel bad for the CFN team - they're always playing catch-up.

Comment: Thanks, the acceleration makes such a massive difference to my uploads, I just want it always on. I will keep an eye open and ensure this answer gets updated when they add the relevant support.

Comment: One option if you want everything included in your CloudFormation stack is to use custom provisioners. Most features are available via APIs right away, before they make it into CloudFormation. You can stick your API calls into an Lambda function to provision features via API calls as CloudFormation custom resources.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html

I have a longer write up on this technique here:
https://www.dwolla.com/updates/bootstrapping-cloudformation-attributes/